# Filter string match without regex

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to filter a column with type string in a a collection result with Like here the logic :

so my logic I want to display all matches when the char before and after my search word in the sentence is in any of my delimiters, if not i don't display the row.

Comment: You're using Entity Framework, not LINQ. LINQ itself can't query databases, nor does it have a `DbFunctions` class. What you want to do requires free text search, you can't do it with `LIKE`

Comment: Why not use regex? Seems to  be a prime example where it could help

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have used IsMatch with regex pattern but than I have an error because linq can't translate that on sql for that I changed with DbFunctions

Comment: @Coder95 are you using EF or LINQ-to-Objests? The query you posted doesn't work at all. You can't use DbFunctions with LINQ to Objects, and `from c in Result ` is invalid in EF. In any case, what you ask can only be done using FTS in the database or reges in memory - or an in-memory FTS engine, but that would require loading all data in memory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes i'm working with entity framework 6 but the method (any) it is linq namescpace system.linq

Comment: @Coder95 which means `Result` is a `DbSet<T>` or an `IQueryable` that comes from a `DbSet<>`. I already explained that what you want requires FTS, you can't use `LIKE` for this. The very fact your query is so complex and frankly unreadable should be a big red warning sign that this is wrong. What SQL query would you write to do what you want? LINQ-to-MySQL can't do anything that's not possible in SQL

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my Result  it is an Iquerable comes from dbset and my query works but I don't have the exact number of rows I don't have an error what I want is to edit my query but it is working. I'm must have 20 rows but now I have just 15 rows with my query

Comment: Use the string split option which takes an array of delimiters : public string[] Split(char[] separator, StringSplitOptions options);

Comment: @jdweng How to modify my query with that please

Comment: DbFunctions.Split(delimiters).Contains("work")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you want is hard to impossible to do using like and string operations in database. And even when you get it right it will be slow. What you should do is use mysql feature [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html). And yes Entity Framework nor linq is supporting this syntax so you will have to circumvent the EF and write that query in a string.

```
_supplierDbContext.Database.SqlQuery<DTO>(
      "select something from table match (column) against (:keywords)",
      new SqlParameter(":keywords",keywords))
```

Comment: It's worth stressing that this will be orders of magnitude faster than `LIKE` and substring operations too, especially if FREETEXT indexes are used. EF 6 can use [Raw SQL queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql) like this by treating them as subqueries around which `Where` and `Select` operations can be added

Comment: I don't have an error in my query also it takes just one seconde, but i didn't understand your solution and where i will write it

Comment: @Coder95 it is not that easy to explain it all in SO format its a big topic; The gist is you create a special kind of index that is language aware, delimiters are ignored, common not that meaning full words (the at on) are ignored. You need to setup it in the database follow the link to the documentation and select there from the options available. In your c# instead of your  linq query you write sql query directly and execute like in my sample.

Comment: your current query is fast because you most likely have a few records in the database. Try inserting few thousand, or even few hundred should be enough to see timeouts on that like query.

Comment: @Rafal My projet  is .net 4.6 to do that I must install entityFrameworkCore andit is not compatible with my version of .net framework in the project using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; to use FromSqlRaw

Comment: no you do not have to have core. [Ef6 supports raw query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql) as presented.